# How do I set the value of p-checkbox programmatically

Tags: primeng

The following code does not produce a error but nothing happens. I'm using ng v11, reactive forms, and primeng 11. What am I missing?

> ```
> <p-checkbox label="Confirm"
>   formControlName="chkConfirm">
> </p-checkbox>
> ```

typescript:

> this.chkConfirm?.setValue(true);

edit:
Adding error message found in console:

> ERROR TypeError: this.model.indexOf is not a function
> at Checkbox.isChecked (primeng-checkbox.js:78)
> at Checkbox.writeValue (primeng-checkbox.js:101)
> at setUpControl (forms.js:2379)
> at FormGroupDirective.addControl (forms.js:5710)
> at FormControlName._setUpControl (forms.js:6285)
> at FormControlName.ngOnChanges (forms.js:6230)
> at FormControlName.rememberChangeHistoryAndInvokeOnChangesHook (core.js:1498)
> at callHook (core.js:2517)
> at callHooks (core.js:2484)
> at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.js:2435)